# Bash script to edit text in csv-format

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting

As part of an inventory bash script I am checking SFP modules and adding them to a .csv-file. The format currently looks like this, with varying lengths:

```
RO01;1000BaseSX SFP;1000BaseSX SFP
RO02;1000BaseSX SFP;1000BaseSX SFP;1000BaseLX SFP
```

My goal is to give each row after the first its own line together with the first row. So the above line should look like this:

```
RO01;1000BaseSX SFP
RO01;1000BaseSX SFP
RO02;1000BaseSX SFP
RO02;1000BaseSX SFP
RO02;1000BaseLX SFP
```

How could I achieve this using text processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solution could be with using `awk`:

```
awk -F";" '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s;%s\n", $1, $i); } }' file
```

With `awk -F";"` we set `FS`(field separator) to `;`. Then for every row(record) we start from field 2 to the last field (`NF`): `for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)` and we print field 1 and current field (`$i`).

Comment: It worked exactly as I wanted, thanks a lot! If it's not troublesome would you care to explain what's happening in this command?

Comment: @Sebbeleu - answer edited.